# Don't Run Async Function if Lock is Locked - Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Suppose that the function takes_time is called every 0.1 seconds on the arguments 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

```py
async def takes_time(i):
    time.sleep(1)
```

After the first second, takes_time(0) will have been run once and takes_time(1), takes_time(2), ..., takes_time(9) are waiting to occur. I want to change this behavior so that those 9 calls are ignored, and takes_time only runs on the arguments 0, 10, 20, 30, etc. It does not matter to me whether they are off by 1 or 2 - I don't care about exactly which numbers are chosen - the main thing is that I want calls to takes_time to be ignored when another call is still running.

Here is my solution:

```py
lock = asyncio.Lock()
async def takes_time(i):
    if lock.locked():
        return
    async with lock:
        time.sleep(1)
```

This solution works partially. It ensures that only one call to takes_time is running at a time, but it does not skip arguments 1 through 9 - even though the lock is locked when they are called. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Because you're using `time.sleep`, which is blocking, and no other call to `takes_time` will be evaluated at all until the current `takes_time` has finished executing. Basically the "ensures only one call is running at a time" is true even without the lock.

Comment: @deceze if I use asyncio.sleep instead of time.sleep, will it skip arguments 1 through 9?

Comment: Yes, then it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should never use blocking calls like `time.sleep()` in asyncio code. (The same applies for blocking network IO like `requests` - there are asyncio libraries for that.) Since you don't need to *wait* for the lock, you probably don't need a full-blown lock in the first place, an ordinary boolean variable would suffice:

```
locked = False

async def takes_time(i):
    global locked
    if locked:
        return
    locked = True
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    finally:
        locked = False
```

In a multi-threaded program, this kind of approach would be subject to a race condition because multiple threads could check `locked` and find it false, both proceeding to set `locked` to true and defeating exclusivity. In asyncio a task switch can occur only on `await` (and additionally `async for` and `async with`). As the code between `if locked` and `locked = True` doesn't `await` anything, it is executed atomically.